# Namespace loop or code leak in boost::function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, namespaces

I'm really baffled by this. Have I managed to do something to cause this, or is it an unclosed namespace block in boost, or some bug in VS c++ 2008? I'm definitely sure I've closed all my own namespaces properly, all includes are outside of and above them, and all my header files got include guards.

[alt text http://lowtown.se/stuffs/superboost.png](http://lowtown.se/stuffs/superboost.png)

The boost/function.hpp is only included in this header. Two other headers in my library includes the boost/cstdint.hpp but they don't have this problem.

Comment: This happens to me all the time. Microsoft's IntelliSense for C++ has always been somewhat broken. If you can afford it, buy VisualAssist.

Comment: "one time load" #defines => Include Guard or Macro Guard. FYI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual C++'s intellisense is a bit quirky. Sometimes it screws up. That doesn't mean there is a problem in your code. Always take C++ intellisense with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes intellisense does that. If you use Visual Assist X it will fix that, but it is a very expensive program :(

Answer (score 2):

Usually deleting ncb-file solves most of Intellisense problems. If it doesn't help — buy VA.